Anyone solved the "longintrepr.h file not found" issue with Colab and Buildozer while convert .py to APK? Using Python 3.12
I'm trying to convert a simple, very simple, python app (.py) in APK using Colab and Buildozer.
At the end I got a fatal error: longintrepr.h file not found....
I have tried to put the file in bin directory but it does not work.
Using Python 3.12 and Buildozer 1.5.1.dev0.
Thank you for any help!!!
Using !Buildozer -v android debug in Colab
